# PHP XML Reading

Tags: php, xml, parsing

How can i retrieve categoryname from given xml file using php

```
<categories>
<category categoryid="1100" categoryname="Baby Clothing" categorylevel="1">
<category categoryid="1101" categoryname="Dresses" categorylevel="2">
</category>
<category categoryid="1102" categoryname="Trousers & Jeans" categorylevel="2">      
</category>
<categories>
```

please help me

Comment: Please provide a short example of the XML you would like to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML you have posted is very invalid (the `&` character *must* be escaped and tags *must* be closed), but here's how to exploit some similar XML using [SimpleXML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

```
$categories = simplexml_load_string(
    '<categories>
        <category categoryid="1100" categoryname="Baby Clothing" categorylevel="1"/>
        <category categoryid="1101" categoryname="Dresses" categorylevel="2"/>
        <category categoryid="1102" categoryname="Trousers &amp; Jeans" categorylevel="2"/>
    </categories>'
);

foreach ($categories->category as $category)
{
    echo $category['categoryname'], "<br />\n";
}
```